# How to run part of a script with reduced privileges?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, shell-script

I have the following problem: On every machine running Postgresql there is a special user *postgres*. This user has administrative access to the database server.

Now I want to write a Bash script that executes a database command with psql as user *postgres* (psql shall execute as user *postgres*, not the script). So far, that wouldn't be a problem: I could just run the script as user *postgres*.

However, I want to write the output of psql to a file in a directory where *postgres* has no write access.

How can I do that?

I thought about changing EUIDs in the script itself, however:

1. I couldn't find a way to change the EUID in a Bash script
2. How can I change the EUID when using something like
   `psql -U postgres -c "<command>" > file`?

Comment: how can I change the password postgres user in subshell (su -c 'psql -U postgres -c "ALTER USER forip PASSWORD \'password\';"' postgres)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a subshell: `(su -c 'psql -U postgres -c "<command>"' postgres) > file`

Inside the subshell you can drop permissions to do your work, but output is redirected to your original shell which still has your original permissions.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to use this trick:

```
{ anycommand } | su -c 'tee file' user
```

[`tee(1)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/tee/) is POSIX utility, so you may rely on its availability.

---

Or, with `sudo`:

```
{ anycommand } | sudo -u user 'tee file'
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea. However, I'm running into two problems: su does not have a -u option, at least on my machine. Running it correctly (su -c command user) leads to another problem, namely that su must be run from a terminal. It probably wouldn't work anyway as su opens a new subshell with that command.

Comment: @Legate have you sudo on your system?

Comment: @ulidtko: Yes, I do.

Comment: then just use `sudo -u postgres psql -c '...' > file` and edit sudoers to disable password prompts for this command

Answer (score 1):

You can run the shell script with user has better write permission (such as root), and when you output the data should write into a folder that database user postgres can write to (such as /tmp)

after data write finish, move it to the directory that your shell script has permission to write (like root user can write in anywhere)

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming up with tricky ways to circumvent security restrictions, you better be asking yourself if your objective is really wise. I know nothing about postgresql - do you really need to be logged in with the admin account to do what you're trying to do, or is there some way you can grant read-only permissions for whatever it is to a normal user account?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, there's no problem in running the script as root, therefore no circumvention of security restrictions occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do it like this: `sudo su postgres -c "psql ..." >/path/to/file`?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However, a quick test with `sudo su postgres -c "echo test"` reveals that such a command does not print anything. Switching to root with `sudo -s` and then executing `su postgres -c "echo test"` does print _test_, so it seems that it is `sudo` that somehow eats the output. I've no idea why though, my guess is that `sudo` and `su -c` use subshells whose stdout is not dragged through to my own shell.

Comment: You must be missing something. `sudo su postgres -c "echo \$USER"` prints `postgres` on my box.

Comment: Well, it works on my Ubuntu notebook, but not on the Debian server where the script has to run.